# Reading SQL Connection from Excel to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, odbc

So my company has an Excel file that makes a SQL connection to a database on our intranet. I want to connect to this database via PHP.

This is what I see from Excel Connection Properties:

[image]

If the actual database was in Excel I would know to make an ODBC connection. But seeing that this is a SQL database I'm not quite sure how to connect to this.

I don't know what the host is and I don't see a password. I'm assuming I would need this to connect to this SQL database.

With only the information shown in the picture, is my only option to make an ODBC connection to the Excel file?

Comment: The database engine is SQLServer...the database name is Glovia Data

Comment: I'm used to seeing (in php) something like: `$db= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=thedatabase;charset=utf8","myusername","mypassword");` But I don't see a password here

Comment: Yes, but when `Trusted_Connetion = Yes` When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.